# Trouble with React: Making component equal to the result of a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

Created a Sandbox where you could see full code:
codesandbox.io/s/elastic-cray-mdpfx?file=/src/visualizations.js

So I first created three React hooks as follows and have already set their state in another function.

```
var [questionsAndAnswersGuide, setQuestionsAndAnswersGuide] = useState({});
var [dataForChart, setDataForChart] = useState({}); 
var [currentQuestionID, setCurrentQuestionID] = useState('Q1');
```

And then I created a function called generateChartData with this function signature

```
const generateChartData = (questionID, data, questionsAndAnswers) => {
    var answersToFrequency = {};
    var chartLabels = [];
    var graphData = [];
    var graphLabel = "Answers";
    var graphBackgroundColors = [
        'rgba(7,221,100,0.6)',
        'rgba(63,130,7, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
        'rgba(54, 162 ,235, 0.6)',
        'rgba(200,7,100)',
        'rgba(255,206,86,0.6)',
        'rgba(75,192,192,0.6)',
        'rgba(153,102,255,0.6)',
        'rgba(255,159,64,0.6)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,0.6)'
    ];
    for(var i = 0; i < questionsAndAnswers[questionID].length; i++) {
        answersToFrequency[questionsAndAnswers[questionID][i]] = 0;
    }
    for(const post of data) {
       if(post[questionID] != "") {
          answersToFrequency[post[questionID]] += 1;
       }
    }
    for(var key in answersToFrequency) {
            if(!isNaN(answersToFrequency[key])) {
                chartLabels.push(key);
                graphData.push(answersToFrequency[key]);
            }
     }
     return {labels: chartLabels, datasets: [{label: graphLabel, data: 
            graphData, backgroundColor: graphBackgroundColors}]};

}
```

And this function returns a dictionary that contains data

Now I created a Chart class that would just display a bar graph.

```
class Chart extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData: props.chartData
            
        }

    }

    static defaultProps = {
        displayTitle:true,
        displayLegend:true,
        legendPosition:'right',
        questionNumber: 'Question 1'
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='chart'>
                <Bar
                    data={this.state.chartData}
                    options={{
                        title: {
                            display: this.props.displayTitle,
                            text: 'Bar Chart for ' + this.props.questionNumber,
                            fontSize:50
                        },
                        legend: {
                            display: this.props.displayLegend,
                            position: this.props.legendPosition
                        }
                    }}
                />
         </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Chart;
```

However, when I say that the chartData should be the result of the function generateChartData, it fails to actually hold the value of the result of generateChartData and in the Chart class, it says that the value of chartData is undefined. How do I properly make chartData equal to the result of function generateChartData?

```
useEffect(() => { <br>
        chart(); <br>
      }, []); <br>
      return ( <br>
        <div className='Visualization'> <br>
            <Chart chartData={generateChartData(currentQuestionID, dataForChart, questionsAndAnswersGuide)} 
legendPosition='bottom'/>
```

However when I do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => { <br>
        chart(); <br>
      }, []); <br>
      return ( <br>
        <div className='Visualization'> <br>
            <Chart chartData={{labels: ['Miami', 'San Francisco', 'Chicago', 'New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Houston'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Population',
                    data: [
                        104343,
                        423424,
                        902114,
                        1000533,
                        156789,
                        78939
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(7,221,100,0.6)',
                        'rgba(63,130,7, 0.6)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                        'rgba(54, 162 ,235, 0.6)',
                        'rgba(200,7,100)',
                        'rgba(255,206,86,0.6)',
                        'rgba(75,192,192,0.6)',
                        'rgba(153,102,255,0.6)',
                        'rgba(255,159,64,0.6)',
                        'rgba(255,99,132,0.6)'
                    ]
                }
            ]
          }
         } legendPosition='bottom'/>
```

It generates the chart for me ad Im not sure where I am going wrong here. Moreover, if I now try this:

```
const generateChartData = (questionID, data, questionsAndAnswers) => {
    var answersToFrequency = {};
    var chartLabels = [];
    var graphData = [];
    var graphLabel = "Answers";
    var graphBackgroundColors = [
        'rgba(7,221,100,0.6)',
        'rgba(63,130,7, 0.6)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
        'rgba(54, 162 ,235, 0.6)',
        'rgba(200,7,100)',
        'rgba(255,206,86,0.6)',
        'rgba(75,192,192,0.6)',
        'rgba(153,102,255,0.6)',
        'rgba(255,159,64,0.6)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,0.6)'
    ];
    for(var i = 0; i < questionsAndAnswers[questionID].length; i++) {
        answersToFrequency[questionsAndAnswers[questionID][i]] = 0;
    }
    for(const post of data) {
       if(post[questionID] != "") {
          answersToFrequency[post[questionID]] += 1;
       }
    }
    for(var key in answersToFrequency) {
            if(!isNaN(answersToFrequency[key])) {
                chartLabels.push(key);
                graphData.push(answersToFrequency[key]);
            }
     }
     return {labels: ['Miami', 'San Francisco', 'Chicago', 'New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Houston'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Population',
                data: [
                    104343,
                    423424,
                    902114,
                    1000533,
                    156789,
                    78939
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(7,221,100,0.6)',
                    'rgba(63,130,7, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(54, 162 ,235, 0.6)',
                    'rgba(200,7,100)',
                    'rgba(255,206,86,0.6)',
                    'rgba(75,192,192,0.6)',
                    'rgba(153,102,255,0.6)',
                    'rgba(255,159,64,0.6)',
                    'rgba(255,99,132,0.6)'
                ]
            }
        ]
      }
```

``    }

```
It fails to actually hold the value of the result of generateChartData and in the Chart class, it says that the value of chartData is undefined.
```

Comment: What does `generateChartData` *actually* return, can you provide complete code and sample return value? Can you also include `Chart`'s code? Where are you validating that chart data is undefined?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese I edited the post just now for you.

Comment: Curious, if you take the hardcoded object that works from your last snippet and return *that* from `generateChartData` does it still work? I suspect it may be because you are saving that `chartData` object into state in the constructor and not using lifecycle functions to react to prop changes, or just not simply passing `chartData` to `Bar` directly, i.e. `data={props.chartData}`, and skipping the local state entirely. Saving props to local state is an anti-pattern for nearly all use-cases, btw. Can you try getting a *running* codesandbox up that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Hi  @DrewReese  https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-cray-mdpfx?file=/src/visualizations.js  Also if I tried returning the hard coded data values from generateChartData, it doesn't set the chartData and from Chart.js it says that the chartData value is undefined.

Comment: Had to find and add a missing `}` as the code in your sandbox wouldn't even compile, and you were missing a `chart.js` dependency. After fixing that and commenting out the data fetch (`fetch("http://localhost:3001/survey")`) I noticed you had the return nested in an `if` statement in `generateChartData`, so once that was moved out to always return a defined object the UI works. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/e4t5p). IMO if the above isn't the cause then I think the issue could be with the `survey` endpoint and whatever it returns that you update state with.